# How to prevent spiders from making webs on my bike?

Tags: maintenance, storage

I really hate spiders and I'm afraid of them so this is really a problem for me. I use bike every day to get everywhere - to work, to shop etc. These nasty things can make a web in a matter of a few hours here (Cambridge, UK) - almost every morning when I want to get to work there is a web, almost every afternoon when I want to go home there is a web. Sometimes there is even a spider. It's really annoying and terrifying. I found this: [How can I keep spiders and other bugs off my bicycle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24000/how-can-i-keep-spiders-and-other-bugs-off-my-bicycle) but it wasn't really helpful. I was thinking about spraying my bike with Raid or something, or maybe spraying it with some kind of water solution with washing liquid and essential oils (I read that some of them repel spiders). Do you have any advice on this? Or maybe at least some advice on dangerous fluids for my bike that I shouldn't use for this? (Like water makes my bike rusty)

Comment: Note that it's not the bike, it's where you're storing it.  I've stored bikes in many different conditions and rarely had problems with spiders on them.

Comment: As to sprays, there is some slight chance that some sort of oil or soap solution would deter spiders, but it would also make a mess of the bike.  Pesticides would be ineffective and dangerous.

Comment: Basically like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Cambridge_CMS_Bicycle_Racks.jpg We have some racks in front of the building where I work and next to the house where I live. Other people store their bikes there too, I noticed webs on those too. And spiders can make their webs during the night or during work hours and I can't really use my bike more than that because I need to sleep and I need to work.

Comment: I did a little searching, and some people have had success with things like peppermint oil, vinegar, or lemon pledge. All that would probably be somewhat safe to apply to your frame, but keep it away from braking surfaces and the drive train. Vinegar is mildly acidic so it might affect the metal, but probably not much if it's painted. [Read this](http://lifehacker.com/deter-spiders-with-peppermint-oil-and-vinegar-1573218277) and do some other research on repelling spiders/insects.